# Educational activities for entering the cyber-security profession?

Tags: professional-education, user-education

This is a question concerning ways that people can get their feet wet with ethical hacking:

https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/1d9onz/how_do_i_start_getting_into_pentesting/

It's an extremely technical field, yet a lot of the time the best way to learn things is through activities (like coding and running programs). You could read an entire book on internet security and still not be able to apply your knowledge in a practical way.

What are some activities you have engaged in that have helped prepare you for a profession in cyber security? Do a lot of cyber security professionals learn what they do through "crime", or is this just a stereotype? Are there certain skill sets that guarantee success in a cyber security profession?

Comment: Security competitions are a great way to start. Just head to [ctftime](https://ctftime.org/), find a competition that runs at a convenient time for you and have at it. There are also wargames like [Hack the box](https://www.hackthebox.eu/). All sorts of great legal ways to get hands-on practice with ethical hacking.

Comment: Cybersecurity is a field with 52 separate job domains. Not all of them are technical. It sounds like you want to know about "ethical hacking" or "bug bounties". If you can define and refine what it is you actually want to do, then the activities will be easier to spot.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but my interests in computer science/security are very broad, and i don't see much of a point in definitions besides talking to other people about these fields, i want to simply learn more about how hackers hack and how info sec. defends without borrowing a ton of money and going to a university. I really liked what tling05 posted unfortunately you are now blocking further recommendations.